# What does Curator mean by in the background?

Tags: apache, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

[Curator's Backgroundable](http://curator.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/curator/framework/api/Backgroundable.html)

What does it mean by running in the background? Is it running in a different thread? The JavaDoc does not say anything. I am unsure :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means asynchronous. ZooKeeper APIs are either synchronous or asynchronous. The synchronous versions wait for completion before returning. The asynchronous versions return immediately and report success/failure via a callback method.